# ESP32-S3-WROOM-1 - LED green diode not working properly

Tags: esp32, led, arduino-esp32

When I try to to set the LED light to full green `neopixelWrite(LED_PIN, 0, 255, 0)`, the LED lights up full red. However, colors which use the green AND other colors work, for example cyan: 0, 255, 255;

Is this a hardware issue? Or can I fix this is software?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: apperantly this esp board uses GRB instead of RGB. I got confused because other esp boards I'd worked with always used RGB.